# In asp.net mvc3 chart helper how to add marker to the series data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In asp.net mvc3 using chart helper, i am trying to draw line chart with number of series. I want to add marker/ highlight the points of a single series.

My Code is

```
var chart = new Chart(900, 500, ChartTheme.Blue).AddTitle("Status: "+ status)
            .SetXAxis("Year", 0, 60)
            .SetYAxis("Age", 0, 30)
            .AddSeries(chartType: "line", xValue: XYear, yValues: YAge, name:"1st series",markerStep:5)
            .AddSeries(chartType: "line", xValue: x1, yValues: y1, name: "2nd series")
            .AddSeries(chartType: "line", xValue: x2, yValues: y2, name: "3rd series")
            .AddLegend()
            .GetBytes("png");


            return File(chart, "image/png");
```

In the 1st series all the points which is given as an input need to be highlighted. How this can be achieved with chart helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class that you're using from **System.Web.Helpers.Chart** namespace isn't as powerful. It will get your some simple charting features but it is really just a wrapper I believe around the real charting framework that Microsoft provides. Look the the Chart object in the namespace **System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting** to do what you're looking to do. I've used this Chart object instead many times and it can do exactly what you're looking to do.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I am finding it much better to get my results.

Comment: Hi! Pls take a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146469/display-label-on-each-bar-chart-in-asp-net-mvc-5-chart